# Yii2 ActiveRecord FindOne() without parameter/s

Tags: activerecord, yii2

How to use findOne() in Yii2 without using any parameters?
i mean querying like
"select top 1 * from table1" or
"select * from table1 LIMIT 1"
Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try This query :

```
   $model=Users::find()->one(); // your model name
```

Answer (score 1):

query like below

```
$user = User::find()->one();
```

Comment: This is better approach for selecting row from huge data.

Answer (score 0):

Also query `$user = User::find()->limit(1)->one();` working faster then `$user = User::find()->one();`